# nodejs get file character encoding

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

How can I find out what character encoding a given text file has?

```
var inputFile = "filename.txt";
var file = fs.readFileSync(inputFile); 
var data = new Buffer(file, "ascii");
var fileEncoding = some_clever_function(file);
if (fileEncoding !== "utf8") {
    // do something
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use external module, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding

Comment: that's exactly what I've been looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The previously mentioned module works for me too. Alternatively you could have a look at [detect-file-encoding-and-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language) which I'm using at the moment.

**Installation:**

```sh
$ npm install detect-file-encoding-and-language
```

**Usage:**

```js
// index.js

const languageEncoding = require("detect-file-encoding-and-language");

const pathToFile = "/home/username/documents/my-text-file.txt"

languageEncoding(pathToFile).then(fileInfo => console.log(fileInfo));
// Possible result: { language: japanese, encoding: Shift-JIS, confidence: { language: 0.97, encoding: 1 } }
```